# Database restore from a hacked system

Tags: postgresql, security

A linux VM with postgres 9.4 was hacked into. (Two processes taking 100% cpu, weird files in /tmp, did not reoccur after kill(s) and restart.) It was decided to install the system from scratch on a new machine (with postgres 9.6). The only data needed was in one of postgres databases. A `pg_dump` of the database was made **after the attack**.

Regardless of whether the data - the tables/rows/etc. - were modified during the attack: **is it safe to restore the database** in the new system?

I consider using `pg_restore` with the -O option (ignores the user permissions)

Comment: `Two processes taking 100% cpu, weird files in /tmp, did not reoccur after kill(s) and restart.` ... could also have been caused by a Java ORM ...

Comment: Well it was surely a malicious process installed probably after postgres was compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two dangers are:

- important data could have been modified
- back doors could have been installed in your database

With the first, you're on your own how to verify that your data are ok. The safest thing would be to use a backup from before the machine was compromized, but this would mean data loss.

For the second, I would run a `pg_dumpall -s` and spend a day reading it carefully. Compare it with a dump from a backup made before the breach. Watch out for weird object and column names and functions with `SECURITY DEFINER`.

Comment: The dump is 33GB though. :)

Comment: If you use the `-s` flag, the output will only contain the object definitions, which should be much less than 33 GB. Veritfying the data themselves is a problem.